# JSON format issue in PHP REST service receiving POST from AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I have a situation where I POST a JSON string from my iOS code using AFNetworking 2.0 code. My client code looks like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonPayloadForProject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"project": jsonString};

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]       initWithBaseURL:url];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[manager POST:@"service.php" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [responseObject description]);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"POST JSON for Project Error"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}];
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "Maps" : [
    {
      "Markers" : [
        {
          "marker_tag" : -790386438,
          "location_y" : 182,
          "location_x" : 344
        },
        {
          "marker_tag" : 451496476,
          "location_y" : 267,
          "location_x" : 150.5
        }
      ],
      "image_string" : "EC817509-DE49-4914-840E-5E407571F6AE.jpeg",
      "order_num" : 0,
      "name" : "Blah1",
      "id" : "EC817509-DE49-4914-840E-5E407571F6AE"
    },
    {
      "Markers" : [
        {
          "marker_tag" : -79601351,
          "location_y" : 377,
          "location_x" : 486.5,
          "image_id" : "Blah2",
          "map_id" : "146C1C09-5AE0-4E4C-83C8-B7EAA8F28A9A"
        }
      ],
      "image_string" : "146C1C09-5AE0-4E4C-83C8-B7EAA8F28A9A.jpeg",
      "order_num" : 0,
      "name" : "1st floor",
      "id" : "146C1C09-5AE0-4E4C-83C8-B7EAA8F28A9A"
    }
  ],
  "longitude" : "-222.222222",
  "latitude" : "33.33333"
}
```

When I read the JSON string on the server in my php code using

```
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

When I do that, I get the following string:

```
{ "project" = '{ \n \"Maps\" : [ \n { \n \"Markers\" : [ \n { \n \"marker_tag\n : = -790386438, \n ....
```

My question is that when I do the following, I get nothing.

```
$array_str = json_decode($json_str, true);
```

What is the best way to put that into an array to parse for data? How can I get back the original JSON string I sent from my client?

Comment: do 1 thing, 
var_dump($POST);exit;
very first line of your script
and see what is the output
or 
echo 'POST Params ';
var_dump($POST);
echo 'GET Params ';
var_dump($GET);
exit;

Comment: @FawadMasud No, this is not a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request. So you don't use `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: For [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer], if I write in my server code: $json_str = json_encode($return_str); echo $json_str; I get error: "unacceptable content-type: text/html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues

1. Your `AFHTTPSessionManager` is using the default `AFJSONResponseSerializer` but merely overriding the `acceptableContentTypes`. You would only do that if your server code was really returning JSON and failing to specify so in the `Content-Type` header.

   - If the server is really not returning JSON, rather than changing `acceptableContentTypes`, you should simply use `AFHTTPSessionManager`

     ```
     manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
     ```
   - or have the server return JSON and make sure it specifies the correct `Content-Type` header:

     ```
     <?php

     $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
     $json = json_decode($json_str, true);

     header('Content-Type: application/json');

     $result = array("received" => $json);
     echo json_encode($result);

     ?>
     ```

     Having done that, I can now simply remove the `acceptableContentTypes` line from the client code altogether and continue to use the default `AFJSONResponseSerializer`.
2. The demonstrated mechanism for building `parameters` is incorrect. You are creating a JSON dictionary with only one item in it, which itself is a string representation of JSON.

   Instead of putting a string representation within the dictionary, I would suggest that you want to put the actual dictionary within the dictionary. So, if you really have a `NSData` of the JSON, convert it back to the nested `NSDictionary`/`NSArray` structure:

   ```
   NSError *error;
   id jsonPayload = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonPayloadData options:0 error:&error];
   NSAssert(jsonPayload, @"json parsing error: %@", error);

   NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"project": jsonPayload};
   ```

   Now, most likely, it will be a little silly to create a `NSData` using `dataWithJSONObject`, only to turn around and extract it back out, but rather you'd just use that original `NSDictionary` within `parameters`, but hopefully this illustrates the point.

So, pulling that all together, assuming you change the server code to return properly formatted JSON response, as outlined above, the client code now becomes:

```
NSError *error;
id jsonPayload = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonPayloadData options:0 error:&error];
NSAssert(jsonPayload, @"json parsing error: %@", error);

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"project": jsonPayload};

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
// manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[manager POST:@"service.php" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [responseObject description]);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error=%@", error);
}];
```

If you do that, you will successfully send your JSON request to the server, it will be parsed, inserted into a new associative array, converted back to JSON and returned to the client app, which will use the default `AFJSONResponseSerializer` to parse it and log it.

Comment: Thanks @Rob for the details. I did all that and now get: error=Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo=0x19f92370 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x19fc9600> { URL: http://blah.com/service.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 26;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:37:51 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.3-1ubuntu2.6";
} },

Comment: if I do this: <?php
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($json_str, true);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$array_str = array("project" => $json);
echo json_encode($array_str);              I get a JSON string back: {
    project =     {
        project =         {  ....      Any Idea?

Comment: Also, if I write `$array_str = array($json);` I only get { project = { .... instead of two "project". How can I filter out the "project" and get only the rest of the body? I didn't set:    `manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]`  ... seems to be returning JSON string back with the "project" in the front.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` stuff (nor the `acceptableContentTypes` stuff). You only need that if your response was not JSON (or was JSON that neglected to set its header properly).

Comment: Thanks @Rob for your help. My intention is not to merely pass back and forth. When I load JSON post into an array on the server and I sent a dictionary with key "project", I don't seem to process the array. But if I just send a JSON string, the array seems to work fine. Is it because of the "project" in the front causing problem? How can I log the received JSON on the server. I did `file_put_contents(filename)` but didn't see any data in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73457/discussion-between-rob-and-user2001457).